# Proving the limit of a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume that 
$$
\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty}| J f(j,J)-g(j,J)|=0,\quad\forall j \in \{1,\cdots,J\}
$$
where

- $f: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to [0,1]$,
- $g: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty)$.

I want to show that
$$
(*) \hspace{1cm}\lim_{J\to\infty}\left| \left(1-\sum_{j=1}^J f(j,J)\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^Jg(j,J)\right)\right|=0.
$$
Below is how I proceed.

- Could you tell me whether my steps are correct (My big doubt is about step (A))?
- In case $(*)$ is wrong, could you specify which additional conditions would help to claim it?
- Lastly, is Step A applicable to the setting in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751845/local-uniform-convergence-of-the-terms-of-a-sum-is-sufficient-for-convergence-of) other question of mine? I guess not (because for that different case the book suggests to go through local uniformity) but I do not understand why.

  ---

$$
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left| J f(j,J)-g(j,J)\right|=0,\quad\forall j \in \{1,\cdots,J\}\\
\Updownarrow\\
\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty}\Big\{ J f(j,J)-g(j,J)\Big\}=0 \text{ }\forall j \in \{1,...,J\}\\
\Downarrow \text{Step (A): following a comment below - still, it is unclear to me how to show this}\\
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left\{ \frac{1}{J} \left(J \sum_{j=1}^Jf(j,J)-\sum_{j=1}^J g(j,J)\right)\right\}=0\\
\Updownarrow\\
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left\{ -\sum_{j=1}^Jf(j,J)+\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J g(j,J)\right\}=0\\
\Updownarrow\\
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left\{ 1-\sum_{j=1}^Jf(j,J)+\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J g(j,J)\right\}=1\\
\Updownarrow\\
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left\{ \left(1-\sum_{j=1}^Jf(j,J)\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J g(j,J)\right)\right\}=0\\
\Updownarrow\\
\lim_{J\to\infty}\left| \left(1-\sum_{j=1}^Jf(j,J)\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J g(j,J)\right)\right|=0 
$$

Comment: Your prove is not correct. For example $\lim \frac 1n = 0$ however $\lim \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1n = 1$
Do you know Cesaro mean ? (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean). It could be helpful to see how to prove that.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that the result I want to prove is false or my way to prove it is wrong?

Comment: I meant that your way is not completely correct but what do you want to prove is true and to prove it you can use Cesaro mean.

Comment: @Youem Could you check whether my edit is correct now? Thank you

Comment: Good ! But is still not correct because in Cesaro mean you have one parameter for the sequence. But in your case you have two $j$ and $J$. However you can adapt the proof of Cesaro mean to your case.

Comment: I am confused: by simply applying the Cesaro's rules, I am tempted to say $
\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty}\Big\{ J f(j,J)-g(j,J)\Big\}=0 \text{ }\forall j \in \{1,...,J\}
$ $\Leftrightarrow $ $\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty} \Big\{ \frac{1}{J}\sum_{k=1}^J (k f(j,k)-g(j,k))\Big\}=0 \text{ }\forall j \in \{1,...,J\}$ But this is not useful (and maybe wrong?) for my exercise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76299/discussion-between-youem-and-cgt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the proposition is not necessarily true.

Counter-example: Take$$
n f(m, n) - g(m, n) = \frac{m^a}{n^b}, \quad \forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}_+
$$
where $a > b > 0$ are constants, then$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} |n f(m, n) - g(m, n)| = 0. \quad \forall m \in \mathbb{N}_+
$$
However,\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m = 1}^n (n f(m, n) - g(m, n)) = \frac{1}{n^{b + 1}} \sum_{m = 1}^n m^a \sim \frac{1}{a + 1} · \frac{n^{a + 1}}{n^{b + 1}}, \quad n \to \infty
\end{align*}
which implies$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \sum_{m = 1}^n f(m, n) - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m = 1}^n g(m, n) \right| = +\infty.
$$

---

Second, a useful but rather strong condition that guarantees the proposition is $h(m, n) := nf(m, n) - g(m, n)$ uniformly tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}_+$, i.e.$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}_+} |h(m, n)| = 0.
$$

---

Last, due to the same reason as that in the counter-example given above, the convergence of Cesaro sum involving two variables is not guaranteed without further condition such as uniformity.

Comment: Thank you. Could you mention in your answer also the other two my sub-questions?

Comment: In particular if you know some sufficient conditions for the proposition to be true

Comment: e.g., $g(m,n)$ monotone, or $g(m,n)\in [0,1]$, $f(m,n)\in [0,1]$, or other

Comment: @CGT I've added (partial) answers to the last two questions.

Comment: Thank you. Would local uniformity work? Could you name or give me a reference for the  result "uniform convergence implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n ... =0$"?