# Local uniform convergence of the terms of a sum is sufficient for convergence of the partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation, uniform-convergence

Consider

- a  mapping $u$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $k \mapsto u(k)\equiv u_k$, bounded in absolute value  by  $\bar{u}<\infty$.
- a  mapping $a$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto (0,\infty)$ with $n\mapsto a(n)\equiv a_n$.
- a  mapping $b$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $n\mapsto b(n)\equiv b_n$.

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, consider the object
$$
n(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))
$$

where (*not sure that all these details are needed*)

- $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$
- $G$ continuous and strictly monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}G(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}G(x)=0$
- $G$ is such that 
  $$
  \exists \text{ }A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty) \text{ s.t. } \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1-G(s+v A(s))}{1-G(s)} = e^{-v}\text{ }\forall v \in \mathbb{R}
  $$
  Moreover, $A(s)\equiv \frac{1-G(s)}{g(s)}$ where $G(s)\equiv \int_{-\infty}^s g(e) de$ $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$.
- $b_n\equiv G^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{n})$, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_{n}=\infty$ (which implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}G(b_{n})=1$)
- $a_n\equiv A(b_n)$.
- Under these conditions it can be shown that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n)=1$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Assume that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))= \exp(-t-x) \text{ }\text{ $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$}
$$
I want to show that  $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}[n(1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n))- \exp(-t-u_k)]=0
$$

---

The book gives two hints:

1) We can see that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $x\mapsto n(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))$ converges locally uniform to $\exp(-t-x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (application of result 0.1 in Resnick's book).

2) Notice that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\exp(-t-u_k)]\leq 1+\exp(\bar{u})<\infty \text{ }\text{ }\forall n\in \mathbb{N} 
$$

---

Which result (with 1) and 2) as sufficient conditions) the book wants me to consider? Could you give some further references or a proof if short?

Comment: Any hint? Thank you

Comment: **Some thoughts**: 
First of all we have to notice that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))= \exp(-t-x) \text{ }\text{ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$}
$$
implies
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big[ \frac{1}{n}n(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))-\frac{1}{n}\exp(-t-x)\Big]=0 \text{ }\text{ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$}
$$
and that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-G(a_n*(t+x)+b_n))=0 \text{ }\text{ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\exp(-t-x)=0 \text{ }\text{ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$}
$$

Comment: Then, using the counting measure, we could apply dominated convergence theorem twice, once to $f_n: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f_n(k)\equiv (1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)$, the other to  $f_n: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f_n(k)\equiv \frac{1}{n}\exp(-t-x)$. Lastly, we could rewrite the integrals as sums. 

However, I am unable to find a function $g$ that is integrable and bounds $f_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've essentially pointed out all of the needed. The fact that, for any $v\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\big(1-G(a_n v+b_n)\big)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-G(b_n+vA(b_n))}{1-G(b_n)}=e^{-v},$$
follows from the conditions on $G$ (it doesn't need to be "assumed" for $v=t+x$).

The result referenced by you is that this convergence is locally uniform, meaning that if $$M_n(v_1,v_2)=\sup_{v\in[v_1,v_2]}\Big|n\big(1-G(a_n v+b_n)\big)-e^{-v}\Big|,$$
then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n(v_1,v_2)=0$, and this is perfectly enough since, obviously,
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\Big(n\big(1-G(a_n(t+u_k)+b_n)\big)-e^{-t-u_k}\Big)\right|\leqslant 2M_n(t-\bar{u},t+\bar{u}).$$